# Centering a line of text in MS Word, but only centered about a portion of the line

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have a table whose column entries I would like centered, like in this link:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onb29.png]

However, I want all the numbers to be beneath each other, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiqsE.png]

The only way I could get it to look proper is to add several spaces to the left of "20" to push the line to the right.  Sometimes this looks ok, but sometimes you can tell the "20" is shifted a bit off-center.  Is there a way I can perhaps highlight only the "20" and center the line about the centre of the "20"?

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a clean way of doing this as requested . Adding spaces is probably the best way to do it, but it has problems, as you found.. How about doing that, but using a fixed-width font so the spacing is always the same?  Or, how about adding a second column to denote "special results"?  That way you can keep your numbers centered in that column the usual way.

Comment: If you care what it looks like, then don't use Microsoft-Word, or any other WYSIWYG.

Comment: Why not split the column, just right of centre? You could then right-justify the numerics in the left-hand column, and left-justify any parentheses in the extra column.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do this is add a left aligned tab stop to the column instead of centering the text and add a tab before each value (it's <kbd>CTRL + Tab</kbd> to add a tab in a table cell BTW).

Note that if the column width changes then you will have to realign the tabstop.

Answer (score 0):

There is “trick” that can simulate the desire effect. First, define the prefer width to the column. Lets says 2 inches. Then for the text inside the column defines an indentation that better fit your desire style. Lets says .75 inches from the left. You should end with a format similar to one that you are like to achieve.